# Different canvas rendering

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

I make a small service for web-masters http://qcoder.ru/pixelfiller/ , but i have one problem. Patterns #7 and #8 ( diagonal lines ) have bad rendering ( with small whitespaces between patterns ) in Mozilla,Safari and Opera. How can i make crossbrowser rendering like in Chrome?

functions for tehese patterns:

```
// #7
function template7() {
    c.beginPath();
    c.moveTo(size, 0);
    c.lineTo(0, size);
    c.stroke();
}

// #8
function template8() {
    c.beginPath();
    c.moveTo(0, 0);
    c.lineTo(size, size);
    c.stroke();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it could be an anti-aliasing problem; from the code snippets you shared it looks like you are drawing a line from one corner to the opposite corner. If you instead draw the line starting and ending a pixel or two outside of the canvas you may see better results:

Bad diagram of what I mean:

```
This:         Not This:

\
 \++++        \++++
 +\+++        +\+++
 ++\++        ++\++
 +++\+        +++\+
 ++++\        ++++\
      \
```

Comment: In that case my next theory is that the adjacent corners (the ones that don't have the line going through them) should have a half triangle because the resulting pattern - according to firefox at least - looks like this: http://i.imgur.com/BZlRZ.png and when it repeats there are two pointed ends touching but not a full line. See this: http://line25.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/patterns/03.png